# Python Selenium to get 'li' text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Python Selenium, I am trying to pull information from the *li* class. Below is the code which I have tried, but I am getting an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

{"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='oas_columnsWrapper']//following::li[2]"}
```

I want to print: `218543-Not Applicable+OA`

Below is the code which I have tried, but no luck.

How can I fix it?

```
print(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='oas_columnsWrapper']//following::li[2]").Attribute("innerHTML"))
```

My HTML code:

```html
<ul class="omniAds__oas_columnsWrapper">
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">1.</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">218543-Not Applicable+OA</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns"></li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">23-11-2021</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">19,452</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">546</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns">3%</li>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns undefined"><b>RUNNING</b></li>
   <div class="omniAds__oas_columns"><a href="/my99acres/all_responses/OA"><b>16 Responses</b></a></div>
   <li class="omniAds__oas_columns omniAds__oas_viewReportBtn" id="oas_viewReportBtn0">View Report</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any method called `Attribute` in Selenium-Python. It is `get_attribute`.

Also, you should add some delay

```
time.sleep(5)
second_li = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='omniAds__oas_columnsWrapper']//following::li[2]").get_attribute('innerText')
print(second_li)
```

Recommendation (use an explicit wait)

```
try:
    second_li = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='omniAds__oas_columnsWrapper']//following::li[2]"))).get_attribute('innerText')
    print(second_li)
except:
    print("Could not get the text")
    pass
```

You will have to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I verifed in the HTML that you've shared, `//ul[@class='omniAds__oas_columnsWrapper']//following::li[2]` is locating the second element.

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath selector is incorrect. It needs to be `omniAds__oas_columnsWrapper`, not just `oas_columnsWrapper`.

Also, you don't need to select the attribute of your WebElement to get its text. Selenium already has a builtin attribute for the WebElement, `.text` to do this for you. However, if you still do want to use attributes, use `.get_attribute()` instead of attribute().

Also, as a side note, I think your XPath can be simplified a bit.